# how to control table view scrolling speed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want control table view scrolling speed?How can I do that programmatically.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Jenson Jacob

Answer (score 9):

You can set `tableView.decelerationRate` property.

*It is a floating-point value that determines the rate of deceleration after the user lifts their finger. And, your application can use the **UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal** and **UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast** constants as reference points for reasonable deceleration rates.*