# How to set scroller speed limit in UITableView cell in IOS ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building an application in IOS. I have use UITableView Cell in my class and I want to set scroller speed limit.

Is there any way to set scroller speed limit. PLease help me I am new in IOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to control table view scrolling speed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731367/how-to-control-table-view-scrolling-speed)

Comment: @Mike tried this link but nothing happen in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tableView.decelerationRate** property for this purpose.

Comment: I want when user finger is on the Screen. It will be great if you help thanks.

Comment: Set your class as UIScrollView delegate, and implement the following delegate method of UIScrollView:

- scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

Comment: What will happen from it can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: This method is called when the scroll view is about to start scrolling the content.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

Comment: I have used as you said here is my code - -(void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.skillSelectionTable.decelerationRate = 0.1;
    NSLog(@"asdasd");
} yet nothing is happing 0.1 value is too less it should scroll slow but it is scrolling very fast yet

Comment: It will not accept values other than UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal or UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have to find alter way to solve my problem

Comment: can you please give me a blog link where navigation Drawer and tab bar are used together. It will really help full

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `tableView.decelerationRate` property.  It determines the speed after a user lifts their finger from the screen.  For the constants, use **UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal** or **UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast**.  For more advanced speeds, you will need to set the decelerationRate property yourself with a floating-point value.

**Edit:**

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast; 
}
```

Comment: I want when user finger is on the Screen. It will be great if you help thanks.

Comment: did you try doing that in the touchesMoved: method?

Comment: How I can use this I don't know please can you explain me in detail or with some example

Comment: its not working can you please give me sample code or blog link